# Magento2 - cannot load custom css - via default_head_blocks.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, css, xml

## UPDATE

Seems that you cannot inherit Luma.... it works properly when inheriting from blank.

github magento source says luma wasn't meant to be inherited.

Challenge is, I really like luma, but need to customize some stuff... so is there a way to do this?

## Original Question:

new to Magento 2, followed the directions to make my own theme, a child of luma theme.

now, I cannot figure out why my default head blocks modification is not working.

I have put developer mode on, cleared cache, and it's not loading my custom css or the external font awesome I tried to link to, this is my code inside default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <!--Custom Styles-->
    <css src="css/cvpstyle.css" />
    
    <!--Before-After Script-->
    <link src="js/jquery.twentytwenty.js"/>
    <link src="js/jquery.event.move.js"/>
    
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url" />
    
</head>
</page>
```

and my folder structure:
[image: my folder structure]

have I structured something wrong? I cannot figure out why this won't work.
Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE

per suggestions below, I changed the directory structure.... still does not work, this is the new directory structure

[image]

my actual XML:
[image: my actual xml]

and here's the folder structure now:
[image: folder structure]

## UPDATE - Jan 29

I have gotten closer to the solution I believe...
I tried making another theme, and inherited from blank instead of luma, and it seems to work, I can see my css and js loaded, but there's literally NO styling on the page of course from blank.

what I wish to do is start with luma, and add some of my custom css...
here is my current XML, is there something wrong with this?

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
 <title>CVPStyle</title> 
 <parent>Magento/luma</parent> 
 <media>
     <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> 
 </media>
</theme>
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue on Magento 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with attempting to inherit from luma.

Inheriting from blank, the custom css and js load properly.

Inheriting from luma, they do not.

source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2547

Answer (score 5):

There's an issue with default_head_blocks.xml if the theme type is set to virtual. Check the type field in the theme table. If it's set to 1, try setting it to 0. Then clear the cache and reload the page. See if that does the trick.

See also: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4330

Comment: You saved my day

Comment: I wasted whole week and I read your solution just before restore the whole freaking server.

Comment: This is still working. Thanks! Impressive this hasn't been fixed yet. Got the issue in 2.4.3

Answer (score 4):

Have you try put layout inside layout dir

basicly theme folder structure is

```
<theme>
  <etc>
  <Vendor_Module>
     <layout>
     <templates>
  <web>
     <css>
     <js>
```

Remove cache and pub/static/area/Vendor/theme may helps you fix problem

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I changed the directory structure and updated my original question above with that info... it still does not work? (pub files cleared, cache flushed, etc)

Comment: You can see theme luma inside folder `\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma` as example. Make sure files like theme.xml, registration.php in root of theme dir have right config

Comment: I tried this, and actually re-made my theme now by copying the luma from where you mentioned.... and I now have: /app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml - but after clearing all cache, etc, it still does not load my custom css or js.

Comment: You should disable cache. Enable developer mode by uncomment inside .htaccess in root magento dir. Clear some folders `var\cache` `var\generation` `pub\static\frontend\Magento` `var\view_preprocessed\css\frontend\Magento` `var\view_preprocessed\source\frontend\Magento`. Finally run command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. Make sure your theme loaded inside backend, find it in left menu Content > Themes

Comment: ok that helps to know what the deploy feature is for... I did all that, exactly in that order, my theme is loaded, but still no custom js or css... I have it as: app > design > frontend > MyVendor > Mytheme > Magento_Theme > layout > default_head_blocks.xml - still isnt working, I think I need to just try and find the core files and try to force my css in there somehow.

Comment: is there another way to add globally a css and js files to the page?

Comment: Yes you can do that by code.Im not understand clearly but this module will help you add css code. Take a look in `vendor\magento\framework\view\page\config.php` This method addPageAsset will allow you do that.  My normal way is put css tag inside head tag of `default_head_blocks` layout of Magento_Theme. It works properly. I have no idea why your theme not work

Answer (score 1):

You have added your `layouts/` as a direct child of your theme. While this works for assets in the `web/` directory, templates and layouts have to belong to a module.

If you move your `layouts/` directory to `Magento_Theme/layouts/`, your `default_head_blocks.xml` should take effect.

Comment: @CVP You have invalid XML. There is no closing `</page>` tag.

Comment: thank you, I do actually... I just didn't paste it here, I missed that line when I pasted into this question, I'll update my original post with my actual xml. So I still have no idea why this thing isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's working with xampp in windows 7 getting the following error whichever theme I choose as parent of my custom theme

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "/pub/static/frontend/My_Custom_Theme/theme/en_US/css/mycustom.css".
(index):17 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "/pub/static/frontend/My_Custom_Theme/theme/en_US/mage/calendar.css".
(index):1 Refused to execute script from '/pub/static/frontend/My_Custom_Theme/theme/en_US/requirejs/require.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```